# how to remove white spaces present in string array of neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

[I want to remove white spaces present inside the array values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3OMF.png)

(I have scor=["1 "," 1"]). Here, first value has white space on right and second value has white space on left. How to remove those white spaces in neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cyper has a rich set of functions for [working with strings](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/).

In your case, you need the [`trim`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/string/#functions-trim) function:

```
UNWIND ["1", "2 ", " 3", " 4 "] as e
RETURN trim(e)
```

Comment: Trim is the right answer, and you can even use this as part of an extract operation to keep it as an array: `RETURN [x in scor | trim(x)] as scor`

Comment: @InverseFalcon Yes, you are right, I constantly forget about this possibility of transforming arrays.